# Java excel: How to compare two cells

Tags: java, excel

I'm looking to see for each row if the value of column 1 is the same or different I've tried adding .getContents() to the end of cell and sheet but it doesn't change the result and tried converting them both to strings but still same result. Every time I've tried it keeps returning "do action 2"

I'm also using JExcelAPI

```
w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
for(int i = 1;i<sheet.getRows(); i++){ 
                 Cell cell = sheet.getCell(0,i);
                 if(cell == sheet.getCell(0, (i+1))){ //If cell is the same value as the one in the row below it
                     //do action 1
                 }
                 else if(cell != sheet.getCell(0,(i+1))){//If cell has a different value as the one in the row below it
                 //do action 2
                 }
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/):*

**First**: You are comparing two different cells, **not their contents**, which is why is always goes to do *action 2*. To get their contents you either say:

```
DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
String content = df.formatCellValue(cell);
```

or

```
String content = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

The advantage of the first code snippet is, that a cell's content doesn't have to be a String, they can also be numeric, without throwing an exception.

**Second**: You have to use the .equals(Object) method instead of the == operator, because the two Strings you will be comparing will never be literally the same object. Also your second if is unnessecary. So your code would look like this:

```
DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();

for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; i++)
{
    Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(i);
    if (df.formatCellValue(cell).equals(df.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0))))
    { //If cell is the same value as the one in the row below it
        //do action 1
    } else
    {//If cell has a different value as the one in the row below it
        //do action 2
    }
}
```

Comment: You put me on the right track but what I found to work was using: 
if(cellOne.getContents().equals(cellTwo.getContents())){

Answer (score 0):

So to get it to work i had to get the cell.getcontents() to return the string value then use .equals() to compare the other cell2.getContents.

```
w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
    Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
    for(int i = 1;i<sheet.getRows(); i++){ 
                     Cell currentCell = sheet.getCell(0,i);
                     Cell nextCell = sheet.getCell(0,(i+1));
                     if(currentCell.getContents().equals(nextCell.getContents())){ //If cell is the same value as the one in the row below it
                         //do action 1
                     }
                     else if(!currentCell.getContents().equals(nextCell.getContents())){//If cell has a different value as the one in the row below it
                     //do action 2
                     }
                 }
```